# Are refresh tokens provided when multiple account are detected on OAuth2 flow?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

By debugging a installed Google Drive application, I've noticed that refresh tokens are not provided after selecting one of the logged Google Account to open/create a new document. When multi account is detected, it is always requested to select one of the users to open/create the document but since no refresh token is found, access token seems to be expired after a while and AppEngine service (according to DrEdit python application) is not able to persist the data on google drive (Internal Error 500).

Is it an issue or my application should handle multi-account in a different way?

Comment: Did you use [web server flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) with offline access? Please make sure your app works with single account logged in first.

Comment: It is an appengine application and OAuth2 flow is handled on server side only. The application is working properly when Google Chrome does not detect more than one logged user. By debugging it I can see that sometimes refresh_token is None